# Catch post action name in observer

Tags: magento-1.9

I have one **extension A** that uses observer for "`couponPost`" action.

I'm developing **extension B** that uses observer and need to have "`couponPost`" action name in it.

If I use `<depends/>` in my **extension B** with **A** as dependent then **extension A** has `couponPost` action, but **B** doesn't have.

How do I get same post action name in **extension B** ?

**Note:** **extension A** is a 3rd party extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to rewritte the extension then you add your second observer

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to write a method on the event in `config.xml` like

```
<controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <Magento_Stack>
                    <class>stack/observer</class>
                    <method>onActionPredispatch</method>
                </Magento_Stack>
            </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch>
```

After that create observer method :

```
public function onActionPredispatch($observer)
{
Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName());
}
```

Comment: Working with the above logic but I can't get quote object, which is NULL